# How to apply tf-idf to rows of text

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I have rows of blurbs (in text format) and I want to use tf-idf to define the weight of each word. Below is the code:

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
    return text
df["punc_blurb"] = df["blurb"].apply(remove_punctuations)

df = pd.DataFrame(df["punc_blurb"])

vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer()
df["blurb_Vect"] = list(vectoriser.fit_transform(df["punc_blurb"]).toarray())

df_vectoriser = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(),
columns = vectoriser.get_feature_names())
print(df_vectoriser)
```

All I get is a massive list of numbers, which I am not even sure anymore if its the TF or TF-IDF that it is giving me as the frequent words (the, and, etc) all have a score of more than 0.

The goal is to see the weights in the tf-idf column shown below and I am unsure if I am doing this in the most efficient way:

[Goal Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYiOP.jpg)

Comment: Please show a [reprex] with input data (as a text) and error message you want to debug. Please also consider [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need punctuation remover if you use `TfidfVectorizer`. It will take care of punctuation automatically, by virtue of default `token_pattern` param:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"blurb":["this is a sentence", "this is, well, another one"]})
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
df["tf_idf"] = list(vectorizer.fit_transform(df["blurb"].values.astype("U")).toarray())
vocab = sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.keys())
df["tf_idf_dic"] = df["tf_idf"].apply(lambda x: {k:v for k,v in dict(zip(vocab,x)).items() if v!=0})
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works but when I tried to change the sentences that you made up and refer to my df["blurb"] column, then the rest of the code doesn't seem to like it. Also with the output, is there a way to only get only the corresponding words to the row? For example, removing the 0.0 words because its not relevant to that row.

Comment: Show a [reprex] please including input as a text

Comment: this is when I changed the df from your sentence example to my column:
df = pd.DataFrame(df1["blurb"])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b')
df["tf_idf"] = list(vectorizer.fit_transform(df["blurb"]).toarray())

ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string

Comment: I showed you a working example. There is no way to help you without seeing your data

Comment: It does not let me show the data. The data is simple, it is an excel sheet with two columns and 7 rows. 
One column for book names and the other column is for book blurbs.
each row is referring to a different book.

Comment: this has worked thanks! I will need to remove the words with scores of zero from the output. for example, 'about' is the only word with a score for that book, the other words with zero, relates to the rest of the other books. Is there a way?

{'100': 0.0, '125': 0.0, '260': 0.0, '30': 0.0, '50': 0.0, 'about': 0.10926942718221799, 'acceptance': 0.0, 'achieve': 0.0, 'across': 0.0, 'actually': 0.0, 'affecting': 0.0, 'after': 0.0, 'air': 0...

Comment: I have already done this with `{k:v for k,v in dict(zip(vocab,x)).items() if v!=0}`. If you still see `0` they are not zeroes, but values close to 0

Comment: Sorry I missed it. It works thanks! Should I be pre-processing my data to remove stopwords before applying the tf-idf function? I just looked at the scores and some scores for 'and/ the/ is/ this/ etc' seems quite high, considering tf-idf is suppose to reduce the weighting of high frequency words.

Comment: tfidf per se does not have an opinion of what is useful or not. It's a preprocessing step among the many possible. A model you train on top your data preprocessing pipeline does have an opinion.